# jOOq Key Produces Bad Query

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I seem to have a bug in jOOq 3.7.3 if we reference a Keys constant twice.  Take the example below:

```
    final Select<Record10<BigDecimal, String, String, String, Timestamp, BigDecimal, BigDecimal, String, String, String>> query = readContext
            .select(li.LIBRARY_ITEM_ID,
                    li.TITLE,
                    li.DETAILED_DESCRIPTION,
                    li.URL,
                    li.CREATE_DATE,
                    li.PORTFOLIO_ID,
                    li.ORGANIZATION_ID,
                    DSL.decode()
                            .when(o_aux_lead_center.ORGANIZATION_ID.isNotNull(),
                                    o_aux_lead_center.ORGANIZATION_NAME)
                            .otherwise(o_lead_center.ORGANIZATION_NAME).as(ORG_NAME),
                    DSL.decode()
                            .when(o_aux_lead_center.ORGANIZATION_ID.isNotNull(),
                                    o_aux_lead_center.ACRONYM).otherwise(o_lead_center.ACRONYM)
                            .as(ORG_ACRONYM), o_resp_mission_dir.ORGANIZATION_NAME)
            .from(li
                    .join(lc.join(lct).onKey(Keys.LC_LCT___FK)
                            .and(lct.CODE_TYPE.equal(LkuCodeTypeLookup.LIBRARY_ITEM_TYPE)))
                    .onKey(Keys.LI_LC_LITI___FK)
                    .and(lc.CODE.equal(LkuCodeLookup.LIBRARY_ITEM_TYPE_NEWS_STORY))
                    // The Portfolio
                    .join(p.join(lc).onKey(Keys.P_LC_ATI___FK)
                            .and(lc.CODE.in(LkuCodeLookup.PORTFOLIO_ACTIVITY_TYPE_TECHNOLOGY))
                            .join(lct).onKey(Keys.LC_LCT___FK)
                            .and(lct.CODE_TYPE.equal(LkuCodeTypeLookup.ACTIVITY_TYPE)))
                    .on(li.PORTFOLIO_ID.equal(p.PORTFOLIO_ID))
                    // The CO for the Portfolio associated with the library item
                    .join(co
                            .join(lc.join(lct).onKey(Keys.LC_LCT___FK)
                                    .and(lct.CODE_TYPE.equal(LkuCodeTypeLookup.OBJECT_TYPE)))
                            .onKey(Keys.CO_LC_OTI___FK)
                            .and(lc.CODE.equal(LkuCodeLookup.OBJECTTYPE_PORTFOLIOS))
                            .and(limitByRelease).join(tu).on(tu.USER_ID.equal(uid))
                            .and(limitBySensitivities))
                    .on(p.PORTFOLIO_ID.equal(co.OBJECT_ID))
                    // The CO for the Library Item
                    .join(co
                            .join(lc.join(lct).onKey(Keys.LC_LCT___FK)
                                    .and(lct.CODE_TYPE.equal(LkuCodeTypeLookup.OBJECT_TYPE)))
                            .onKey(Keys.CO_LC_OTI___FK)
                            .and(lc.CODE.equal(LkuCodeLookup.OBJECTTYPE_LIBRARY_ITEMS))
                            .andExists(
                                    readContext
                                            .selectFrom(cos)
                                            .where(cos.CORE_OBJECT_ID.equal(co.CORE_OBJECT_ID))
                                            .and(cos.SECTION
                                                    .equal(BigDecimal
                                                            .valueOf(AccessControlConstants.CORE_OBJECT_CHAR_ARRAY_SELF))
                                                    .and(cos.SENSITIVITIES.equal(BigDecimal.ZERO)))))
                    .on(li.LIBRARY_ITEM_ID.equal(co.OBJECT_ID)))
            // The Responsible Mission Directorate
            .leftOuterJoin(
                    po
                            .join(o_resp_mission_dir)
                            .on(po.ORGANIZATION_ID.equal(o_resp_mission_dir.ORGANIZATION_ID))
                            .join(lc)
                            .onKey(Keys.PO_LC_ATI___FK)
                            .and(lc.CODE
                                    .equal(LkuCodeLookup.ASSOCIATIONTYPE_RESPONSIBLE_MISSION_DIRECTORATE))
                            .join(lct)
                            .onKey(Keys.LC_LCT___FK)
                            .and(lct.CODE_TYPE
                                    .equal(LkuCodeTypeLookup.PORTFOLIO_ORGANIZATION_ASSOCIATION_TYPE)))
            .onKey(Keys.PO_P___FK)
            // The Portfolio Organizations
            .leftOuterJoin(
                    po
                            // Add in the organization data
                            .join(o_lead_center.leftOuterJoin(o_aux_lead_center).on(
                                    o_lead_center.REPLACEMENT_ORGANIZATION_ID.equal(
                                            o_aux_lead_center.ORGANIZATION_ID).and(
                                            o_lead_center.IS_ACTIVE.equal(byteZero))))
                            .on(po.ORGANIZATION_ID.equal(o_lead_center.ORGANIZATION_ID))
                            .join(lc)
                            .onKey(Keys.PO_LC_ATI___FK)
                            .and(lc.CODE.equal(LkuCodeLookup.ASSOCIATIONTYPE_LEAD_CENTER))
                            .join(lct)
                            .onKey(Keys.LC_LCT___FK)
                            .and(lct.CODE_TYPE
                                    .equal(LkuCodeTypeLookup.PORTFOLIO_ORGANIZATION_ASSOCIATION_TYPE)))
            .onKey(Keys.PO_P___FK)
            .orderBy(
                    DSL.decode().when(li.UPDATE_DATE.isNull(), li.CREATE_DATE)
                            .otherwise(li.UPDATE_DATE).desc());
```

That generates a bad SQL query (Oracle 12C):

```
select 
  "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ITEMS"."LIBRARY_ITEM_ID", 
  "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ITEMS"."TITLE", 
  "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ITEMS"."DETAILED_DESCRIPTION", 
  "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ITEMS"."URL", 
  "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ITEMS"."CREATE_DATE", 
  "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ITEMS"."LIBRARY_ID", 
  "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ITEMS"."ORGANIZATION_ID", 
  case when "AuxLeadCenter"."ORGANIZATION_ID" is not null then "AuxLeadCenter"."ORGANIZATION_NAME"
       else "LeadCenter"."ORGANIZATION_NAME"
  end "ORG_NAME", 
  case when "AuxLeadCenter"."ORGANIZATION_ID" is not null then "AuxLeadCenter"."ACRONYM"
       else "LeadCenter"."ACRONYM"
  end "ORG_ACRONYM", 
  "RespMissionDir"."ORGANIZATION_NAME"
from "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ITEMS"
  join (
    "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"
      join "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"
      on (
        "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID"
        and "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."CODE_TYPE" = 'LIBRARY_ITEM_TYPE'
      )
  )
  on (
    "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ITEMS"."LIBRARY_ITEM_TYPE_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."LKU_CODE_ID"
    and "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."CODE" = 'NEWS_STORY'
  )
  join (
    "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY"
      join "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"
      on (
        "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY"."ACTIVITY_TYPE_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."LKU_CODE_ID"
        and "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."CODE" in (
          'MISSION_WITH_TECHNOLOGY', 'TECHNOLOGY_ONLY'
        )
      )
      join "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"
      on (
        "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID"
        and "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."CODE_TYPE" = 'ACTIVITY_TYPE'
      )
  )
  on "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ITEMS"."LIBRARY_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY"."LIBRARY_ID"
  join (
    "SCHEMA_A"."AC"
      join (
        "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"
          join "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"
          on (
            "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID"
            and "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."CODE_TYPE" = 'OBJECT_TYPE'
          )
      )
      on (
        "SCHEMA_A"."AC"."OBJECT_TYPE_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."LKU_CODE_ID"
        and "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."CODE" = 'PORTFOLIOS'
        and exists (
          select 
            "SCHEMA_A"."AC_RELEASE_TYPES"."AC_ID", 
            "SCHEMA_A"."AC_RELEASE_TYPES"."SECTION", 
            "SCHEMA_A"."AC_RELEASE_TYPES"."RELEASE_TYPE", 
            "SCHEMA_A"."AC_RELEASE_TYPES"."CREATE_DATE", 
            "SCHEMA_A"."AC_RELEASE_TYPES"."CREATED_BY", 
            "SCHEMA_A"."AC_RELEASE_TYPES"."UPDATE_DATE", 
            "SCHEMA_A"."AC_RELEASE_TYPES"."UPDATED_BY"
          from "SCHEMA_A"."AC_RELEASE_TYPES"
          where (
            "SCHEMA_A"."AC"."AC_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."AC_RELEASE_TYPES"."AC_ID"
            and "SCHEMA_A"."AC_RELEASE_TYPES"."SECTION" = 1
            and "SCHEMA_A"."AC_RELEASE_TYPES"."RELEASE_TYPE" in (
              6, 7
            )
          )
        )
      )
      join "SCHEMA_A"."TP_USERS"
      on (
        "SCHEMA_A"."TP_USERS"."USER_ID" = 456920
        and exists (
          select 
            "SCHEMA_A"."AC_SENSITIVITIES"."AC_ID", 
            "SCHEMA_A"."AC_SENSITIVITIES"."SECTION", 
            "SCHEMA_A"."AC_SENSITIVITIES"."SENSITIVITIES", 
            "SCHEMA_A"."AC_SENSITIVITIES"."CREATE_DATE", 
            "SCHEMA_A"."AC_SENSITIVITIES"."CREATED_BY", 
            "SCHEMA_A"."AC_SENSITIVITIES"."UPDATE_DATE", 
            "SCHEMA_A"."AC_SENSITIVITIES"."UPDATED_BY"
          from "SCHEMA_A"."AC_SENSITIVITIES"
          where (
            "SCHEMA_A"."AC"."AC_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."AC_SENSITIVITIES"."AC_ID"
            and "SCHEMA_A"."AC_SENSITIVITIES"."SECTION" = 0
            and bitand(
              "SCHEMA_A"."TP_USERS"."SENSITIVITIES", 
              "SCHEMA_A"."AC_SENSITIVITIES"."SENSITIVITIES") = "SCHEMA_A"."AC_SENSITIVITIES"."SENSITIVITIES"
          )
        )
      )
  )
  on "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY"."LIBRARY_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."AC"."OBJECT_ID"
  join (
    "SCHEMA_A"."AC"
      join (
        "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"
          join "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"
          on (
            "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID"
            and "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."CODE_TYPE" = 'OBJECT_TYPE'
          )
      )
      on (
        "SCHEMA_A"."AC"."OBJECT_TYPE_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."LKU_CODE_ID"
        and "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."CODE" = 'LIBRARY_ITEMS'
        and exists (
          select 
            "SCHEMA_A"."AC_SENSITIVITIES"."AC_ID", 
            "SCHEMA_A"."AC_SENSITIVITIES"."SECTION", 
            "SCHEMA_A"."AC_SENSITIVITIES"."SENSITIVITIES", 
            "SCHEMA_A"."AC_SENSITIVITIES"."CREATE_DATE", 
            "SCHEMA_A"."AC_SENSITIVITIES"."CREATED_BY", 
            "SCHEMA_A"."AC_SENSITIVITIES"."UPDATE_DATE", 
            "SCHEMA_A"."AC_SENSITIVITIES"."UPDATED_BY"
          from "SCHEMA_A"."AC_SENSITIVITIES"
          where (
            "SCHEMA_A"."AC_SENSITIVITIES"."AC_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."AC"."AC_ID"
            and "SCHEMA_A"."AC_SENSITIVITIES"."SECTION" = 0
            and "SCHEMA_A"."AC_SENSITIVITIES"."SENSITIVITIES" = 0
          )
        )
      )
  )
  on "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ITEMS"."LIBRARY_ITEM_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."AC"."OBJECT_ID"
  left outer join (
    "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ORGANIZATIONS"
      join "SCHEMA_A"."ORGANIZATIONS" "RespMissionDir"
      on "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ORGANIZATIONS"."ORGANIZATION_ID" = "RespMissionDir"."ORGANIZATION_ID"
      join "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"
      on (
        "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ORGANIZATIONS"."ASSOCIATION_TYPE_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."LKU_CODE_ID"
        and "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."CODE" = 'RESPONSIBLE_MISSION_DIRECTORATE'
      )
      join "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"
      on (
        "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID"
        and "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."CODE_TYPE" = 'PORTFOLIO_ORGANIZATION_ASSOCIATION_TYPE'
      )
  )
  on "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ORGANIZATIONS"."LIBRARY_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY"."LIBRARY_ID"
  left outer join (
    "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ORGANIZATIONS"
      join (
        "SCHEMA_A"."ORGANIZATIONS" "LeadCenter"
          left outer join "SCHEMA_A"."ORGANIZATIONS" "AuxLeadCenter"
          on (
            "LeadCenter"."REPLACEMENT_ORGANIZATION_ID" = "AuxLeadCenter"."ORGANIZATION_ID"
            and "LeadCenter"."IS_ACTIVE" = 0
          )
      )
      on "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ORGANIZATIONS"."ORGANIZATION_ID" = "LeadCenter"."ORGANIZATION_ID"
      join "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"
      on (
        "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ORGANIZATIONS"."ASSOCIATION_TYPE_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."LKU_CODE_ID"
        and "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."CODE" = 'LEAD_CENTER'
      )
      join "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"
      on (
        "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID"
        and "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."CODE_TYPE" = 'PORTFOLIO_ORGANIZATION_ASSOCIATION_TYPE'
      )
  )
  on "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ORGANIZATIONS"."LIBRARY_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ORGANIZATIONS"."LIBRARY_ID"
order by case when "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ITEMS"."UPDATE_DATE" is null then "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ITEMS"."CREATE_DATE"
              else "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ITEMS"."UPDATE_DATE"
         end desc
```

The workaround I found to remove the second reference to Keys.PO_P___FK and replace it with the actual key, but is anyone else seeing this?  Does anyone know why it properly sets the data to `"SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ORGANIZATIONS"."LIBRARY_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY"."LIBRARY_ID"` the first time, but the second it causes a cross-join because it sets the on to `"SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ORGANIZATIONS"."LIBRARY_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ORGANIZATIONS"."LIBRARY_ID"`?

Comment: The problem here is probably that the `LIBRARY_ID` column is ambiguous in the join table tree at the stage when the second `onKey()` method is called. Do you see any warning in the logs? There should be a warning since jOOQ 3.7.3, when ambiguous lookups are made (https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5047)

Comment: I've seen the warnings that you are talking about when I just do an empty `onKey()` call if I'm joining something that has subjoins, but not when I do an `onKey(ForeignKey<?, ?> key)` call.  I've actually done an `onKey(ForeignKey<?, ?> key)` call in jOOq (stupidly, I might add) against an aliased table, which jOOq, of course, allowed, but that kicked off a SQL exception because (obviously) jOOq put in the ForeignKey, just as I had asked but didn't use the alias.  Out of curiosity, is there a good way to pull the FKs out of an aliased table?

Comment: There was an issue that should have been fixed: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2870. May be worth a separate question, if the issue still persists, or if the fix wasn't complete?

Comment: Hmmm... the problem is that I am doing `onKey(Keys.<FK_NAME>)` against an alias and because some are against inner joins where multiple tables are joined, I cannot use `onKey()` because it tells me it's ambiguous.  Maybe I'll look into that a little and post separately, but the two things are slightly different, I think, since one is the `onKey()` that figures out the Keys to use and the other is me specifying the `Keys` entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ON KEY` join method is translated to an ordinary `ON` join predicate by finding the "best" matching tables on both sides. There is a bug ([#5209](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5209)), by which the foreign key table in the key is matched *first*, and upon match the primary key table is not validated. Because of this, the key is resolved in the wrong direction.

In your query, the `"SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ORGANIZATIONS"` table is joined twice without renaming:

```sql
left outer join (
    "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ORGANIZATIONS"
      join "SCHEMA_A"."ORGANIZATIONS" "RespMissionDir"
```

And:

```sql
  left outer join (
    "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ORGANIZATIONS"
      join (
        "SCHEMA_A"."ORGANIZATIONS" "LeadCenter"
```

This ambiguity cannot be resolved correctly by jOOQ. You should see a warning in the log files as of jOOQ 3.7.3 ([#5047](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5047)) indicating that your usage of `onKey()` couldn't be resolved non-ambiguously.

In general, it's probably a good idea to avoid `onKey()` when the join table trees become too complex.

Comment: Blast it (regarding your last sentence)!  Do you know how much I adore `onKey(Keys.XXX)` calls?  Actually, I'd really love to be able to pump in multiple FKs (for those rare times where it is useful).  I love that I can just do `onKey(Keys.%ChildTableAcr%_%ParentTableAcr%___FK)` and not have to worry about what that FK really says (so if it changes, I just rebuild my jOOq code and life is good).

As for the body, is it really ambiguous?  I'm calling `onKey` with a `Keys` entry.  I am pretty sure that I could do such a call with a Keys entry for two other tables and jOOq will put it in.

Comment: I agree that using `onKey()` is nice, but it is also treacherous, because it is not explicit. As the query grows, the semantics might become ambiguous, when it wasn't at first. I suspect, though, that you're right in this case, and there's a bug. The ambiguity arises only because the direction of the key is detected only based on the foreign key table (ambiguous), not also based on the primary key table (non-ambiguous). I have created an issue for this: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5209. Thanks for reporting!

Comment: I'm glad that you found a simple means of reproducing!  I was afraid that it might be one of those complicated things.  Thank you for opening up the ticket and for the explanations/discussion!

Comment: @DanO: I was afraid of this too, but luckily, it's a "simple" issue :)